# What is the simplest way to emulate key press in console application?

Tags: java, java-io

I need to press Enter programmatically in order to stop my program. I need something like this:

```
public class EnterPress {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //press enter programmatically

        String readString = scanner.nextLine();
        while (readString != null) {
            if (readString.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Enter obtained!");
                break;
            }

            if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                readString = scanner.nextLine();
            } else {
                readString = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`

Comment: @a_a I tried this, but this emulate key press where my cursor is. So if my cursor is, for example, in IDE, your code snippet will make new line in my java code. This won't be a console input.

Comment: Do you actually need the keypress, or do you just need your program to stop?

Comment: What's the use case here? Why do you need to read something that you enter yourself programmatically?

Comment: My task is to finish program after 5 seconds by artificial enter press. So I put to sleep my main thread for 5 seconds and do what listed in code snippet above.

Comment: What kind of a task is that supposed to be.

Comment: Full task: There is class Spam that receive messages and intervals for those messages to be displayed(so, it works like message[i] -> Thread.sleep(interval[i]) and so on).  If user presses enter - stop the program. Make artificial enter press after 5 seconds.